# How else can i optimize my bundle and improve page speed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, webpack, webpack-2

I have a react application where many library has been used like redux, redux-form, react-router, leaflet, react-bootstrap, redux-thunk and many more. My bundle size is minified to 531kb and vendor file to 5.32mb.

I have used webpack for bundling and optimization. Also i have used code splitting in webpack and react router. What else can be done for better performance in speed and as small size as possible. Does anyone has any idea to share?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  'react', 'lodash', 'axios', 'base-64', 'leaflet', 'leaflet-routing-machine',
  'moment', 'react-bootstrap', 'react-dates', 'react-dom', 'react-geosuggest',
  'react-google-places-suggest', 'react-input-range', 'react-intl', 'react-leaflet',
  'react-masonry-component', 'react-redux', 'react-router', 'react-router-redux',
  'react-slick', 'redux', 'redux-form', 'redux-thunk'
];

const config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader'
        }),
        test: /\.css$/,
      },
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: { limit: 40000 }
          },
          'image-webpack-loader'
        ],
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
      },
      {
        test: /masonry|imagesloaded|fizzy\-ui\-utils|desandro\-|outlayer|get\-size|doc\-ready|eventie|eventemitter/, // eslint-disable-line
        loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false&this=>window'
    }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        })
    );
}

module.exports = config;
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = {
  component: App,
  path: '/',
  childRoutes: [
    {
    component: HomeLayout,
    indexRoute: { component: Apartament },
    childRoutes: [
      {
        path: 'apartamentos',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./containers/homescreen/apartament-form')
             .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'signup',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./containers/homescreen/signup')
             .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./containers/homescreen/login')
             .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  {
  component: ResultLayout,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'car',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./containers/result/car-result')
        .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      }
    },
  ]
}
  ]
};
```

Is there any other tips/idea like code splitting and shouldComponentUpdate?

Sorry for my bad English.

UPDATE after implementing @Tholle idea

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `NoErrorsPlugin` and fine tune the options to `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `UglifyJsPlugin` to make the bundles smaller:

```
const config = {
  ...,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true
      }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      },
      mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        screw_ie8: true
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Firstly, huge thanks to you for your idea regarding minification. I implemented your idea and the size of bundle.js is reduced to 413kb from 531kb and vendor size is reduced to 1.56mb from 5.33mb. However i am getting warning on dedupe which i have updated in my question.

Comment: @Apprentice No problem. Ah, my mistake. I thought you were using Webpack 1. Do you get any warnings if you just remove `new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),`?

Comment: i did not get any error when removing DedupePlugin(). I get only warning regarding the size which is there from the start WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (250 kB). This can impact web performance.

Comment: @Apprentice I see. That's a tricky situation. You don't have any libraries that are only used on certain pages or in popups etc. that you can break out into a separate chunk?

Comment: react-masonry-component is used only in homepage(destinos.js and its a child component of HomeLayout which you can see above in routes.js). Also leaflet and leaflet-routing-machine is used only in result page like (car, apartment which are a child component of ResultLayout).